# Compare DateTime objects in extbase

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I am trying to compare `date.starttime` with `today`. The below code doesn't work like supposed.

```
<f:for each="{appointments}" as="appointment">

  <f:for each="{appointment.dates}" as="date">

    <f:if condition="{f:format.date(date: date.startdate, format: 'Y-m-d')} == {f:format.date(date: today, format: 'Y-m-d')}">
      <f:then>

          <p>{appointment.id} // {appointment.location}<p>

      </f:then>
    </f:if>

  </f:for>
</f:for>
```

today gets assigned inside my controller:

```
$today = new \DateTime('today');
$this->view->assign('today', $today);
```

**How can i figure out if `date.starttime` (DateTime object) is today??**

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. I haven't closed the if condition with `</f:if>`. Thought thats not necessary as i used `if` in an other view (without closing the tag) and had no problems. And i additionally used "=" instead of "==" for the condition.